# JUnit, DBUnit with HSQLDB for JUnit test cases. How to create tables ? before any test starts..No Hibernate or other ORM I am using

Tags: junit, hsqldb, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I am using DBUnit with HSQLDB for JUnit test cases. I am not able to create tables using @DatabaseSetup.. How to create table when a test case starts using DBUnit + HSQL without ORM provider

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "I am not able to crate tables"?  Do you mean you dont have permissions? or you just can't use the `@DatabaseSetup`  annotation.

You will have to programatically create the tables using the SQL `CREATE TABLE` command:

[example tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)

If you can't use `@DatabaseSetup` you can always create the database and populate it with whatever records you need in a `@Before` annotated setup method.  Just remember to also clean up your db by dropping tables etc in a corresponding `@After` method